# Error logging propagation when using Akka Supervision

Tags: scala, akka

Here's the thing am kinda stuck at. I have a SupervisorActor which creates Actor A and B and so on. There are no child actors to ActorA or ActorB.Lets say both Actor A and B hit Database and get SQL exception. This is propagated to the SupervisorActor up the chain. When I catch SQL exception, I also need to Log that Actor A had a SQL exception. But how can I achieve this?

- 1 way I could think is my Actor A logs it and throws an exception above the call stack. But I would need a try-catch block in my code. Which kinda defeats the purpose here.
  Creating
- Another way, I can think of is Actor A and B create a new child Actor A1 which would send it up the chain but that's not an option coz that's a common library without actors.

Is there a way to achieve something similar to :
Yes! I wanted to know if we can achieve something like:

```
 try{
    saveUser()
  }
  catch {
    case b: BatchUpdateException =>     
        logger.error("We received a BatchUpdateException when trying to save the user")
        throw b
      }
    case e: Exception =>
      logger.error("Some other exception occured ")
      throw e
  }



try{
    saveSeller()
  }
  catch {
    case b: BatchUpdateException =>     
        logger.error("We received a BatchUpdateException when trying to save the Seller details")
        throw b
      }
    case e: Exception =>
      logger.error("Some other exception occured ")
      throw e
  }
```

PS: Am not sure if supervision strategy is the right approach to achieve what I am trying to achieve. I am trying to explore new possibilities.

Comment: so you need to log from which actor you are getting the exception?

Comment: @RamanMishra Updated my post

Comment: try raising custome exceptions according to the actor who is failing.

Comment: To do that I need to have try catch block right, in that case there is no point of having the supervisor actor right.

Comment: Use TRY{}match  not try catch

Comment: Yeah sure. Try match sounds reasonable but i was trying to compare what do I gain by having a supervisor actor, if we can’t handle logging over using custom try catch or Try match.

Answer (score 0):

Centralizing fault-handling logic within a supervisor actor using [SupervisorStrategy](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/SupervisorStrategy.html) is a better approach than scattering/duplicating it across individual actors.  In particular, expressing the `Exception`-handling logic as the `decider` parameter of type `PartialFunction[Throwable, Directive]` helps improve code maintainability.

> When I catch SQL exception, I also need to Log that Actor A had a SQL exception. But how can I achieve this?

Within the supervisor actor, you can always log `Exception`s from individual child actors within the supervisor actor by including the corresponding actor references via `sender`.  Below is a trivialized example of a supervisor actor logging actor-specific `Exception`s from a couple of child actors and taking corresponding `Resume/Stop/Escalate` actions:

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, Props, ActorLogging}
import akka.actor.OneForOneStrategy
import akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import java.sql.SQLException

implicit val system = ActorSystem("system")
implicit val ec = system.dispatcher

case class CreateWorker(props: Props, name: String)
case class BogusQuery(ex: Exception)

def doQuery(q: BogusQuery) = throw q.ex

class MySupervisor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  override val supervisorStrategy =
    OneForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 5, withinTimeRange = 1.minute) {
      case e: SQLException =>
        log.error(s"Supervisor: $e from $sender; Resuming!")
        Resume
      case e: NullPointerException =>
        log.error(s"Supervisor: $e from $sender; Stopping!")
        Stop
      case _: Exception =>
        log.error(s"Supervisor: Unknown exception from $sender; Escalating!")
        Escalate
    }
  def receive = {
    case w: CreateWorker => sender ! context.actorOf(w.props, w.name)
  }
}

class MyWorker extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  def receive = {
    case q: BogusQuery =>
      log.info(s"$self: Received '$q'!")
      doQuery(q)
    case x =>
      log.error(s"$self: Unknown value '${x}'!")
  }
}

val supervisor = system.actorOf(Props[MySupervisor], "supervisor")

supervisor ! CreateWorker(Props[MyWorker], "workerA")
supervisor ! CreateWorker(Props[MyWorker], "workerB")

val workerA = system.actorSelection("/user/supervisor/workerA")
val workerB = system.actorSelection("/user/supervisor/workerB")

workerA ! BogusQuery(new SQLException)
// [INFO] [<timestamp>] [<dispatcher>] [akka://system/user/supervisor/workerA]
//   Actor[akka://system/user/supervisor/workerA#-2129514903]:
//     Received 'BogusQuery(java.sql.SQLException)'!
// [ERROR] [<timestamp>] [<dispatcher>] [akka://system/user/supervisor]
//   Supervisor: java.sql.SQLException from
//     Actor[akka://system/user/supervisor/workerA#-2129514903]; Resuming!
// [WARN] [<timestamp>] [<dispatcher>] [akka://system/user/supervisor/workerA] null

workerB ! BogusQuery(new NullPointerException)
// [ERROR] [<timestamp>] [<dispatcher>] [akka://system/user/supervisor]
//   Supervisor: java.lang.NullPointerException from
//     Actor[akka://system/user/supervisor/workerB#-1563197689]; Stopping!
// [ERROR] [<timestamp>] [<dispatcher>] [akka://system/user/supervisor/workerB] null
// java.lang.NullPointerException ...
```